# How to reflect/highlight manually entered months on the monthpicker using DoCheck [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-docheck

I need your help. I'm literally blocked because of a simple thing. I've created a stackblitz also but first I'll explain the problem. It's quite complicated, please bear with me. I've created a time range selector of my own. A valid range is this: 02-01-2019 - 09-01-2020. The format is `mm-dd-yyyy`. I've created a proper UI for this. The selections can be made in two ways:

1. By clicking on the months. [This feature is working perfectly]
2. By entering dates manually [This is not working. Here I need help]

I'm also doing basic validation using `moment`:

1. Valid years are [2016, 2019]
2. `startRange` should not be after `endRange`'
3. Format should be `mm-dd-yyyy`

Note: `startRange` and `endRange` are two `[(ngModel)]` bind variables for start end end range's input fields respectively.

**monthpicker.component.html**

```
<div class="wrapper" [class.warning-border]="isApplied">
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="startRange" class="start-range custom-input-field">
   ....
   <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="endRange" class="end-range custom-input-field">
   ....
</div>
```

Here's the list of important methods in **monthpicker.component.ts**:

1. `onClick(indexClicked)` - This method is called whenever a month name is clicked. This is for making selections using mouse clicks. It is working fine as of now.
2. `triggerReflection()` - This method should be called when I enter the dates through keyboard. This will call the validation method `validate(startRange,endRange)` which will check above mentioned criteria. If both ranges are good, then finally `monthReflection()` is called which will actually reflect the selection on the month picker tray.

Here's the code:

```
triggerReflection() {
    ....
      ....
        this.validate(this.startRange, this.endRange);
        if (this.isValidRange) {
            this.monthRangeReflection();
        } else {
            this.isValidRange = false;
        }
    } ....
}
```

But the reflection is not happening. I've checked many solutions. I'm using `DoCheck` as I want the validation to happen as I type-in the dates:

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.validate(this.startRange, this.endRange);
    console.log("ngDocheckCalled");   
}
```

I want the reflection on the range on the month tray automatically if the range is valid. I don't want to use `(keydown)=triggerReflection()` because then I'll have to press some key. I don't want that. Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-munp7i). Please find the component `monthpicker`. This only we've to fix.

Feel free to ask for more information. Please help me. I've tried many solutions, now Stackoverflow is my last hope.

Comment: I'm continuously trying to figure out the problem. But no success yet :-(

Comment: Can we do something from its parent component i.e. **timeselector**. I'm also trying that approach.

Comment: If inside `ngDoCheck` I replace `this.validate(this.startRange, this.endRange);` with `this.triggerReflection();` Then It works, but then I loose selection by mouse click.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is the same as in your other question. Subscribe to the `valuesChanges` observable of your input fields. With just a couple of lines of code you can call the `this.triggerReflection` when the user enters the dates manually. You have to set up the subscription in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook:

```
export class MonthpickerComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck, AfterViewInit {
    @Output() outputToParent = new EventEmitter<string>();
    @Output('timeselectorValidation') timeselectorValidation: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    @ViewChildren(NgModel) dateRefs: QueryList<NgModel>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.dateRefs.forEach(ref => 
        ref.valueChanges.subscribe(() =>
          this.triggerReflection()
        )
      )
    }
```

Check the Stackblitz I forked from your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dcugua. The above is the only change I made (plus added a console.log in the triggerReflection method).

Comment: Actually that's why I asked that question. Thanks for your answer Kari. Let me implement this. I'll get back to you shortly.